# What's the gradle equivalent for mvn clean eclipse:clean?

Tags: maven, gradle

What's the gradle equivalent for `mvn clean eclipse:clean`?

I'm looking to delete files created by Eclipse through command. Is this possible?

Comment: `eclipse:clean` is long deprecated and should not be used any more.

Comment: How can we delete .gradle, .settings, bin, .classpath etc folders?

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: I dont see any reason to push it into repository

Comment: Just gitignore it.

Comment: If you like to delete is put them into `.gitignore` and you can do `git clean -fdx`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using one of the [Gradle Eclipse Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) (`plugins { id 'eclipse' }`), you can delete all Eclipse-specific files using the task `cleanEclipse`. Since the task `clean` from the Gradle Java plugin acts as an eqiuvalent to `mvn clean`, you could use the following command to achieve a similar behavior.

```
gradle clean cleanEclipse
```

Please note that there is no one-to-one mapping between Maven functionality and Gradle functionality, so there may be files affected or not affected by one command or the other.

---

As others have already suggested, you should ignore files you will never want to push to version control by using the respective version control feature (e.g. a `.gitignore` file when using Git).